# Updater is not upgrading

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, sudo

I am using Ubuntu 12.10. I tried to upgrade it using the Software Updater, but it is not working even after pressing Upgrade button. Then I tried to upgrade through the terminal using the command `sudo apt-get upgrade`. I got the following error message:

```
sudo: unable to change to sudoers gid: Operation not permitted.
```

Please help.

Comment: try `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` in the terminal.

Comment: Thanks for your cooperation. Surprisingly when I opened the computer yesterday night, it is found that everything was fine and upgrading to 13.04 was also done without any hindrance. I think there was internal problem in 12.04 itself.

Comment: @JonathanRogiest Thank U for above comment, It helped Me!

Answer (score 0):

You may have to upgrade through downloading the ISO for 13.04 and burning it to a DVD. I had a similar problem long ago and that was the only solution.

It shouldn't delete your personal data, but always backup!